Where should exceptions be throwed in a hexagonal architecture?
I'm changing 3 layer architecture to hexagonal architecture.
In hexagonal, Should the exception be throwed in the adapter or in the service?
This is code I write.
I use Kotlin, Spring, JPA.
Once I throw exception in service. (EntityNotFoundException)
give me feedback!

Might this will help!

Domain Layer

InvalidOrderStateException,
InsufficientBalanceException


Application Layer

Catching a DatabaseConnectionException and throwing a
DataAccessException.


Adapter Layer

EntityNotFoundException
DatabaseConnectionException




Aha! I got it! Thank you ^^
